# Spring integration IMAP- folder closed exception

Tags: spring-integration

I'm trying to get basic Imapmailreceiver using spring integration and i stumbled up a sticky folder closed exception.
I constantly get **Folder closed exception** when reading the content of the email, But the I am able to get the subject correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**1. My application Context is as follows**

```
<int:channel id="emails"/>

<util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
    <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
    <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
    <prop key="mail.store.protocol">imaps</prop>
    <prop key="mail.debug">false</prop>
</util:properties>
<int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter id="mailAdapter"
                             store-uri="ACTUALCREDENTIALHERE"
                              java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties"
                              channel="emails"
                              should-delete-messages="true"
                              auto-startup="false"
                              should-mark-messages-as-read="true" />
<int:service-activator id="receiveEmail" input-channel="emails" ref="MessageReceiver"/>
<bean id="MessageReceiver" class="org.springframework.integration.mail.imapidle.MessageReceiver" />
</beans>
```

**2. The Main APP as follows**

```
    ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/META-INF/spring/integration/gmail.xml");


 ImapIdleChannelAdapter ic=(ImapIdleChannelAdapter)ac
    .getBean("mailAdapter");

    ic.start();
```

**3. The service activator is as follows**

```
public class MessageReceiver {
    public void handle(javax.mail.Message message){
        MailToStringTransformer m2s = new MailToStringTransformer();
            m2s.setCharset("utf-8");


//payload instanceof MimeMultipart
            if (message instanceof MimeMessage) {
                try {
                 System.out.println("inside mimemessagehandler");
                   // javax.mail.Message mailMessage = (javax.mail.Message) payload;
                    System.out.println(message.getSubject());
                    System.out.println(getTextFromMessage(message));

                    Address[] receipts = message.getAllRecipients();
                    System.out.println("RECEIPIENTS MAIL ID");
                    if (receipts != null && receipts.length > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < receipts.length; i++) {
                            System.out.println(((InternetAddress) receipts[i]).getAddress());
                        }
                    }

                    System.out.println("FROM MAIL ID");
                    Address[] froms = message.getFrom();
                    String email = froms == null ? null
                            : ((InternetAddress) froms[0]).getAddress();
                    System.out.println(email);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }



    private static  String getTextFromMessage(javax.mail.Message message) throws Exception {
    String result = "";
    if (message.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
        result = message.getContent().toString();
    } else if (message.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
        MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = (MimeMultipart) message.getContent();
        result = getTextFromMimeMultipart(mimeMultipart);
    }
    return result;
}

private static String getTextFromMimeMultipart(MimeMultipart mimeMultipart) throws Exception {
    String result = "";

    int count = mimeMultipart.getCount();
    System.out.println("CCC "+count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
       // mimeMultipart.toString()
        BodyPart bodyPart = mimeMultipart.getBodyPart(i);
        if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
           result = mimeMultipart.toString();//(String) bodyPart.getContent();

        } else if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/html")) {
            String html = (String) bodyPart.getContent();
            // result = result + "\n" + org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(html).text();
        } else if (bodyPart.getContent() instanceof MimeMultipart) {
            result = result + getTextFromMimeMultipart((MimeMultipart) bodyPart.getContent());
        }
    }
    return result;
}

}
```

--- EXCEPTION

```
javax.mail.FolderClosedException

      at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.getContent(MimeBodyPart.java:659)
      at org.springframework.integration.mail.imapidle.MessageReceiver.getTextFromMimeMultipart(MessageReceiver.java:101)
      at org.springframework.integration.mail.imapidle.MessageReceiver.getTextFromMessage(MessageReceiver.java:83)
      at org.springframework.integration.mail.imapidle.MessageReceiver.handle(MessageReceiver.java:41)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at
```

Comment: You need to show the complete stack trace; you might also get some clues by setting `mail.debug` to `true`. Also, why do you have user classes in a package under `org.springframework.integration.mail`? That's just weird. User classes should be in their own (non-framework) package.

Comment: @GaryRussell, take a look, please, into my answer.

Comment: @GaryRussell  full stack trace here https://gist.github.com/badrisugavanam/ad96fcd2fabf66244b66f5487cda51d8

Answer (score 1):

Well, looks like we can't get content from the `MimeBodyPart` if `Folder` is closed already. And looks like we have exactly this situation in the `AbstractMailReceiver.receive()` :

```
            }
                return converted;
            }
            else {
                return filteredMessages;
            }
        }
        finally {
            MailTransportUtils.closeFolder(this.folder, this.shouldDeleteMessages);
        }
```

Not sure why we close folder there after receiving but before sending dowstream, nevertheless I'd suggest you to try with the `DefaultMailHeaderMapper` for the `ImapMailReceiver`. In that case the content of the `MimeMessage` is converted to the `org.springframework.messaging.Message` internally in the mentioned `AbstractMailReceiver.receive()`:

```
if (this.headerMapper != null) {
                org.springframework.messaging.Message<?>[] converted =
                        new org.springframework.messaging.Message<?>[filteredMessages.length];
                int n = 0;
                for (MimeMessage message : filteredMessages) {
                    Map<String, Object> headers = this.headerMapper.toHeaders(message);
                    converted[n++] = getMessageBuilderFactory().withPayload(extractContent(message, headers))
                            .copyHeaders(headers)
                            .build();
                }
                return converted;
            }
```

Meanwhile, please, raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) on the matter and we consider to fix that `Folder.close()` inconsistency. In my best feeling that should not be done at all or we should provide it for end-user as a header to let him/her decide when and where to close the folder if that.

Comment: Have the same issue, couldn't delete received emails because folder was already closed inside receive function

Comment: "Delete message" ? Looks like not related story to the question. We have talked about `getContent()` before...

Comment: Yes, but why are you closing folder, as I understand, after doing that all retrieved emails couldn't be changed, like for example I would've wanted to set Deleted flag on one of the emails(in order to apply it I should call folder.expunge method), but the folder was already closed inside retrieve function. What is the purpose?

Comment: Please, move all this questions and concerns to that JIRA. The SO doesn't have value already on the matter.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Can you please show me an example to get the headerMapper from channel adapter from the config file

Comment: Here we go : http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/reference/html/mail.html#mail-mapping. There is a proper description for the `DefaultMailHeaderMapper`

Comment: Thanks, @ArtemBilan I figured how to inject the  DefaultMailHeaderMapper now will post after I complete the reading the content but looks straight forward to read from the map

Comment: @ArtemBilan still getting folder closed exception unable to get actual content of a mulipartmime message.I even tried using 

Caused by: javax.mail.FolderClosedException
 at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.getContent(MimeBodyPart.java:659)
 at org.emailreader.integration.mail.imapidle.MessageReceiver.getTextFromMimeMultipart(MessageReceiver.java:89)
 at org.emailreader.integration.mail.imapidle.MessageReceiver.receive(MessageReceiver.java:49)
   
 full details on gist @ https://gist.github.com/badrisugavanam/849d5d915eedd02763849cc5e9a7b21c

Comment: In the current version the folder is closed before the exit of the `MailReceiver` anyway. So, your `getTextFromMimeMultipart()`  tries to get content from the closed object already. Try with the `embedded-parts-as-bytes="true"`. So, all the content will be resolved in the `MailReceiver` already. What you will need in your component is just a proper `byte[]` conversion to the target content

Comment: @ArtemBilan, any news on this ? Folder close is still in code (current version), so we are unable to read MimeMessage attachments in handler. A workaround that you describe in jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4299 does not work as well, because in AbstractMailReceiver.postProcessFilteredMessages(Message[]) you convert instances of MimeMessage to IntegrationMessage and drop all message numbers to 0. So even in reopened folder it is not possible to locate the same message by number.

Comment: What new would you like to hear? Sorry, the conversion is too long and too old already. There is that JIRA https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4299. Feel free to comment there whatever you think makes sense.

Comment: @ArtemBilan, sorry, sent too short message by mistake - now edited (above).

Comment: Good. Please, comment that in the JIRA. I'm not so good with Java Mail. Maybe someone else will answer you.